# editar una imagen subida a phpmyadmin

Tags: php, html, css

Tengo varias imágenes subidas a PHPMyAdmin y quiero elegir una de ellas y poder editarla con CSS para cambiar el tamaño sin que afecte las demás, como podía hacerlo, necesito una gran ayuda porfa.
estoy usando este método para guardar

```php
<?php

    include("conectar.php");
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));

    $query =  "INSERT INTO registros(nombre,imagen) VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen')";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

    if ($resultado){
        header("location: mostrar_2.php");
    }

    else{
        echo "nose inserto";
    }
?>
```

Además, para mostrar la imagen en HTML, uso el siguiente código

```html
      <body>    
            <center>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><a class="note" href="index_2.php">Subir</a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </center>
            <tbody>
            <?php
                include("conectar.php");

                $query = "SELECT * FROM registros";
                $resultado = $conexion->query($query);
                while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img class="img" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']); ?>"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <?php 
                }
            ?>  
            </tbody>
</body>
```

Agradezco a quien me pueda dar una solución, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es guardarle atributos a la imagen cuando la registres en la base de datos.

Para ello tendrías que modificar la estructura de tu tabla (agregando los atributos que necesitas)

```
$query =  "INSERT INTO registros(nombre,imagen, alto, ancho) VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen', 'alto', 'ancho')";
```

y asignandolo en la etiqueta html de imagen

```
<img class="img" width="<?php echo $row['ancho'] ?>" height="<?php echo $row['alto'] ?>" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($row['imagen']); ?>"/>
```

Ya para seleccionarlo tendrías que usar JavaScript para crear la funcionalidad en el front.

```js
// esta funcion recibe el parametro enviado desde del html,  en este caso le envio la etiqueta html a la que esta apuntando this.
function seleccionar(label){
  console.log(`Imagen ${label.id}`);
  // aqui pondria la logica de lo que desea que haga el programa
}
```

```html
<img id="1" onclick="seleccionar(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="30%"/>

<img id="2" onclick="seleccionar(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="20%"/>

<img id="3" onclick="seleccionar(this)" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="10%"/>
```

Como sugerencia, no guardes la imagen directo en la base de datos, sino que guardes solo el nombre del archivo y almacenas la imagen en el servidor, además de usar [sentencias preparadas](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) para evitar inyección de sql.

Comment: perdon por molestarte bro, pero eso de almacenar la imagen en el servidor como lo hago o de que tema es para investigarlo, aparte muchas gracias por  la ayuda que me diste

Comment: claro amigo, no hay problema, para almacenarlo dentro de una carpeta especifica, tendrías que hacer algunos procesos extra en tu función php, este es una guía de como almacenar imágenes en el servidor: https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/upload-de-imagenes-con-php/

Comment: bro perdon por molestarlo otra ves pero si subo las fotos con php de la manera que dijiste es sseguro o hay otra forma mucho mas segura para subirlas? gracias por toda la ayuda.